# Regex pattern only matches an odd number of characters when it should match all characters up to 12 in length

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I am using regex to validate a form control in angular that concatenates several patterns into the form control's validator.

Here is my component's TS related to the form. Please ignore the repeated \w regex as it is converted from an old system and I cannot change it. I do however need to make sure the regex from all these validate the same field. The important part is `^(.{8,12})$`

```js
let regex = new RegExp('(^\\w\\w\\w \\w\\w\\w$)|(^(.{8,12})$)|(^\\w\\w\\w[,] \\w\\w\\w$)','g');
this.controls["regexInput"] = new FormControl(code.Value, Validators.pattern(regex));
```

here is my html

```html
<mat-form-field class="mat-inputs">
    <input matInput [name]='pattern' [formControlName]='regexInput'>
    <mat-error *ngIf='controls["regexInput"].hasError("pattern")'>Input does not match pattern.</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Inputs that should **not** match:

- 123
- 123abc123abc123abc123abc
- 1234567

Inputs that should be valid:

1.) 123 abc

2.) 123, abc

3.) 123456789

4.) 123456789012

The form correctly validates all but #3, and similarly any string of 8 < length <= 12 will work as long as it has an even number of characters. Why do only an even number of characters validate properly while odd numbers fail?

Comment: The pattern seems to work as expected for me: https://regex101.com/r/uPMetn/1

Comment: Yes me too. However when I use this regex in my Angular Form Control's validator it comes back with unexpected behavior.

Comment: I suspect the answer is "remove `'g'`"

Comment: Thanx, Wiktor! Removing 'g' worked for me.